# flutter - How to warning user about session time out and force user re-login?

Tags: flutter

I was wondering how to check session time out on mobile application and popup warning user re-login. Such as Bank application if you leave screen for a while warning pop up will show up and force user to re-login. Any idea?

Comment: hmmm i think you can achieved it maybe with hive and background fetch package in pub e.g. make a user to save locally on phone which the hive then on that you may used background fetch to do the task like a timer but to do that it you only be trigger on when the app is killed or close.  Then after couple a while you may force the user to re-login again or after showing you session is expired or something

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your app inside `GestureDetector` to detect user's last interaction and then use [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html) to show the Dialog to login again after a certain time. If the user interacts with the app during before the specified time, then the Timer can be cancelled and new timer can be created.

Comment: Interesting I will try this one.